# Training a Text Detection System

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, ocr

I'm currently developping a text detection system in a given image using logistic regression, and I need training data like the image below:

[image]

The first column show a positive example (y=1) of text wheras the second column show images without text (y=0).

I'm wondering where I can get a labeled dataset of this kind??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to start for these sorts of things is the UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

But maybe also consider heading over to Cross-Validated as well, for machine learning-related questions:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't find the kind of dataset that I'm looking for, but it this site will come handy in the futur. thanks

Comment: There's an interesting article here discussing datasets as well: https://medium.com/@olivercameron/20-weird-wonderful-datasets-for-machine-learning-c70fc89b73d5#.758g2kl5n

Answer (score 2):

You can get a similar dataset [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/text/).

Hope it helps.